# How can I import a project's start and finish dates from excel using VBA?

Tags: ms-project

How can I import a *project's* start date and finish date -- the ones you would see in this Project Information window:

[image]

I would think to use an approach like the following, where I have been able to import values for the Project Department and Customer, but I can't figure out how to do the same for the project Start date and Finish date.

To begin with, I can't even find the field names for the project's Start date and Finish date.

```
ActiveProject.ProjectSummaryTask.SetField FieldNameToFieldConstant("Project Departments"), dept
ActiveProject.ProjectSummaryTask.SetField FieldNameToFieldConstant("Customer"), customer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ProjectStart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.project.projectstart) and [ProjectFinish](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.project.projectfinish) dates are at the project-level. Use ***either*** of these like this:

```
ActiveProject.ProjectStart = #5/1/21#
ActiveProject.ProjectFinish = #12/1/21#
```

Projects can be scheduled either from a start date or a finish date but not both. The other date will be calculated based on the tasks in the schedule.

Setting the ProjectStart field automatically sets the [ScheduleFromStart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.project.schedulefromstart) field to True. Likewise setting the ProjectFinish field sets it to False.